# Curve shape on Mesh

Tags: modeling

Is there a way of getting a nice smooth curve without using the subsurface modifier on a mesh. 
But maintaining clean topology and not using booleans. I tried some methods but with no particular luck. I added many subdivisions with the intentions of getting a nice curve. But once I add the circle tool, it becomes a mesh.

[image]

Comment: Why without using a subsurf modifier?

Comment: The previous models which I had uploaded I had used a modifier, So this is more of a problem solving inquiry. to gain new skills and theory from the forum. (Also the Subsurface modifier was causing some unwanted issues on the model I practising on). So I'd like to know if there's a way of achieving a smooth curve. Even If there's an Ad-On I'd like to know.

Comment: This was one of the methods I done it using subsurface. Now I'd like to gain more skills knowing to achieve it without subsurface modifier.

https://ibb.co/WDqJQ3X

Comment: Don't waste your time. Proper usage of the subsurf modifier is the main skill you need when it comes to modeling and it's the common way of polygonal modeling for many years now. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *Subdivision Surface* is not convenient, you can do it manually.

- Start with a circle - it's way easier than to shape vertices into a circle later
- Since you're not using subdivision, flat n-gons aren't a problem.

[image]

- Use *Bevel* to make edges softer.
- note that *Bevel* is more limited by tight corners

[image]

Comment: More polygons, add more, more polygons! ;)

Comment: Certainly :). When modeling without subsurf, 256 verts for a circle isn't unusual :). Still, using subsurf is just sooo much easier.

Comment: Tried to explain that already: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173378/curve-shape-on-mesh/173401?noredirect=1#comment291355_173378 but I think that's a waste of time too :D

Comment: Well, for flat, angular objects, Bevel can be enough. The polycount easily gets down to 1/10 of subdivided geometry. And I too had a (short-lived) interest in modeling entirely without subsurf :).

Comment: Thanks for the demo Jachym. 

At starters I was a bit confused. But then I realised that it was done using a circle and a square mesh. I also added the steps which I followed. 
https://ibb.co/cNmKzWR

Kind regards.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful :). And good luck with your project.